# Clicking on an element, if present, in webdriverio

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

I'm using the latest Appium and webdriverion versions to test a native app, and what I need to do in my script is Click on a Button if it exists, but continue if it doesn't.

So, if the `Accept and Close` button is present it will be clicked, and then the subsequent `Allow` button will be clicked.

But, if the `Accept and Close` button isn't present, then it will go straight to the next command and click the `Allow` button straight away.

My code currently looks like this;

```
        if (await expect(await closeCMP).isExisting()) {
                    await closeCMP.click()

    } else {
                  var allow = await $('~Allow');
                  await allow.click();
        }
    });
});
```

However, if the `Accept and Close` button isn't present then the test fails (with a timeout error, as the `Accept and Close` element cannot be found) rather than perform the next command (which is to click on the `Allow` button).

Is there an obvious reason for this?

Also, do I need the `else` part of the loop, or will just the `if` part of the loop suffice?

I appreciate that some may perceive this as bad practice, but I'm not able to alter anything on the DOM, or do anything with Cookies so I'm not sure what else I can do to get this to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but do you need to just "Accept and Continue" if the button is present, or is its existence a test specification that needs to be tested? I'm asking this, because you're expecting `closeCMP` to be existing, otherwise why would you use an `expect`?

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to do this, but I generally use `try/catch` blocks to prevent tests from failing when evaluating conditionals.

Here's an example of how it could look using this approach.

```
try {
    await expect(await closeCMP).isExisting();
    await closeCMP.click();
} catch {
    console.warn('one of the previous lines threw an error');
}
const allow = await $('~Allow');
await allow.click();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you response. So I've edited my script to be;

```it('close cmp & popups', async () => {

  browser.setImplicitTimeout(40000);

  let closeCMP = $('~ACCEPT AND CLOSE');

  if (await closeCMP.isExisting()) {

   await closeCMP.click();

  } else {

   console.log('element is not displayed');

  }

  let allowButton = await $('~Allow');

  await allowButton.click();```
 
but I'm still getting an error. if Accept & Close button not there, it fails and the Allow button is not clicked. And ideas?

Comment: You could try using a try/catch block rather than if/else. The `if(await closeCMP.isExisting())` is the reason why this test fails when the button doesn't exist. You're using a mocha(?) test evaluation, one that can cause a test to fail, as a boolean when it does not really evaluate to a boolean.